# Intermittent wireless connection in Ubuntu but not in Windows

Tags: wireless, wireless-access-point

I am new to Ubuntu. My wireless connection on Ubuntu is not consistent. It connects then  disconnects and playing an ON and OFF game. Please suggest some solution.

Is there something that I have change in software because it works pretty good on Windows?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please see this question [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and edit your question and post the appropriate informations.

Comment: We would need your Ubuntu version and follow Nikth's link to post a better question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using either 12.04 or 12.10, the problem appears to have been solved about a week ago by updating the system. I too had the same problem, it was fixed by updating. So do the following:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

After that reboot and you should be done. Of course, all of this assuming you have not yet done this and have 12.04/12.10.